# Select from dropdown list to multiply two cells then input result into another

Tags: excel, function, drop-down-menu, vlookup, multiplication

I have a simple spreadsheet for tracking my hours worked and pay, depending on which job function I perform that day. Tech= $10, Video= $20.

I've made a dropdown list for my two different job functions in cell "H5". I have my hours worked in cell "G5" and I want my wage earned to appear in cell "I5". On my second sheet "Data" I have my to jobs listed in cells "A1, A2" and their corresponding wages in cells "B1, B2".

I want to be able to select my job from the dropdown list on the first sheet and have my hours from Cell "G5" automatically multiplied by the associated wage from the Data sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=G5*VLOOKUP(H5,Sheet2!A1:B2,2,0)
```

Comment: Perhaps I should of clarified that this is a daily tracker so I need to be able to select a different job daily without it effecting the other days.

This did work but now if I switch which job I did, it changes it for every day, their all linking together now.. The cells in I column that is.

Comment: I figured it out what the problem was. I just needed to change the number on the G and H columns in the formula to correspond with which row I'm on for each day.. Works great, thanks again.. I'm unable to upvote right now but will when I can..